# How to add an api proxy on netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, netlify

I have added my proxy on package.json and it works perfectly when i run it .But, Whenever, I build my react site.The app stops posting data on api. What could be the reason.
As well as , same thing happens with netlify as well.

Comment: Please include some code showing what is working and what isn't so contributors can understand the issue and help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try official documentation.

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/api/something"
  to = "https://api.yourapi.com"
  status = 200
  force = true
  signed = "API_SIGNATURE_TOKEN"
```

Read more at
https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#proxy-to-another-service